# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY even after selecting that column issue

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I was writing one query in which there is one join and one group by but on executing the query i got this error which is quite common but for reference this was the error

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ipay_app.sp.code' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

the query is

```
select sp.code,count(sps.sp_key) 
from service_providers sp
left join service_providers_sub sps
on sp.code = sps.sp_key
group by sps.sp_key;
```

[image: image one before adding group by]

but when i am adding sp.code in group by clause i am getting expected result .

[image: image two after adding group by]

just wanted to make sure why ?

Comment: In your query it is mandatory to group by  `sp.code` if  it is part of the select list and not part of an aggregate function.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/3404097)

Answer (score 2):

Your select has a non-aggregated column (`sp.code`) and an aggregate function (`count(sps.sp_key)`). Therefore you need to include the non-aggregated column to `GROUP BY`:

```
select sp.code, count(sps.sp_key) 
from service_providers sp
  left join service_providers_sub sps on sp.code = sps.sp_key
group by sp.code;
```